# How can I change the django-behave test runner's test file discovery pattern?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-unittest, python-behave

I have a Django project with behave features and unittest tests. The unittest tests are organized like so:

```
theproject/
    theapp/
        tests/
            tests_one.py
            tests_other.py
            ...
```

It is irritating to have to prefix test files, which are already clearly identified as such by being in the `tests` directory, with "tests_".

If I rename all the test files without "tests_" and change my test runner to

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
```

in settings.py and do

```
python manage.py test -p '*.py'
```

all of my unittest tests run, but not my behave features.

When I have

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_behave.runner.DjangoBehaveTestSuiteRunner'
```

in settings.py and do

```
python manage.py test
```

my features run but not my unittest tests.

The django-behave runner doesn't have a `-p` flag or an equivalent that I can see.

How can I get the django-behave runner to discover tests in files whose names don't begin with "tests_"?

Comment: I'm not using behave, but would also like to change what files are searched for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by switching from django-behave to behave-django.

behave-django does not need the Django TEST_RUNNER to be set to its own test runner, so `python manage.py test -p '*.py'` works.

behave-django doesn't provide a single Django management command that runs both unit and acceptance tests. I solved that problem by writing a new management command.